# Передача данных с сервера на клиент

Tags: javascript, node.js, клиент-сервер

Есть такая переменная на клиенте:

```
 var sprite_param = function() {
    this.size = 14;
    this.speed = 1;
    this.amount = 1;
}
```

И такая переменная в файле server.js для node.js :

```
     var controlPanelParametrs = {
        "size" : size.param,
        "speed" : speed.param
     }
```

Как передать данные с сервера на клиент, чтобы получилось что-то вроде :

```
var sprite_param = function() {
    this.size = controlPanelParametrs.size;
    this.speed = controlPanelParametrs.speed;
    this.amount = 1;
}
```

Не используя socket.io!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как часто надо получать эту переменную? Для динамического общения сервера с клиентом я использовал сокет в своем учебном проекте, но это куча зависимостей и привязка к аутентификации, если нам надо знать, какому клиенту что отправлять. В вашем случае можно использовать лонгпуллинг, так, например, реализованы уведомления Вконтакте. Напишите на сервере обработчик get запроса по определённому  маршруту, например "/getspeed", который бы отвечал нужными данными: `res.send(controlPanelParametrs)`, а на фронтэнде приложения напишите AJAX Get запрос по этому адресу:

```
(function poll() {
   setTimeout(function() {
       $.ajax({ url: "/getspeed", success: function(data) {
            sprite_par.size(data.size);
            sprite_par.speed(data.speed);
       }, dataType: "json", complete: poll });
    }, 30000);
})();
```

Эта функция сама запускается первый раз и по успешному выполнению снова себя запускает рекурсивно, чтобы обновить значение. setTimeout() необходим, чтобы отправить запрос снова, если будет таймаут.

Comment: Кстати читал, что для игр, потокового видео и прочих штук, где важна скорость обновления информации, используются сокеты, так как они значительно быстрее.